# Changes made are not reflecting on my website

Tags: html, dns, ip, server

I am not a regular HTML coder. I need to remove some of the contents in my company's website which is a single file written in basic HTML. I found the file and removed all the things which needed to removed. All the changes I made are showing up if I browse my website using the IP address of server where my website is been hosted but if I browse using my company's domain name changes made are not appearing. What can be the possible wrong thing am I doing? Any help will be help full.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can be your browser cache, you can empty it with the following shortcut: ctrl + f5 or on a mac ctrl + shift + r.